# redeclaration of enumerator "..."

Tags: c, enums

I am currently writing a code which uses boolean enum which I coded like this:

```
typedef enum {
  false = 0,
  true = 1
} Bool;
```

but when I try and compile the code it prints an error:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -ansi AsMaker.c
In file included from analyze_str.h:1:0,
                 from AsMaker.c:2:
storage.h:15:3: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘false’
   false = 0,
   ^
In file included from AsMaker.c:1:0:
storage.h:15:3: note: previous definition of ‘false’ was here
   false = 0,
   ^
In file included from analyze_str.h:1:0,
                 from AsMaker.c:2:
storage.h:16:3: error: redeclaration of enumerator ‘true’
   true = 1
   ^
In file included from AsMaker.c:1:0:
storage.h:16:3: note: previous definition of ‘true’ was here
   true = 1
   ^
In file included from analyze_str.h:1:0,
                 from AsMaker.c:2:
storage.h:17:3: error: conflicting types for ‘bool’
 } bool;
   ^
In file included from AsMaker.c:1:0:
storage.h:17:3: note: previous declaration of ‘bool’ was here
 } bool;
```

I have more enum declarations of other things with different enumerators and they get that error as well.
Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Please post the whole error message.

Comment: Are you including the header file more than once (possibly through another file)?  Make sure you guard it against multiple inclusion.

Comment: It's enough until the next `error:`. The whole error messages is since `error:` untill `error:` or `warning:`.

Comment: Thanks. You have several #include "storage.h" from AsMaker.c, the second one is indirect from analyze_str.h. Please learn about  header guards usage.

Comment: FYI you can use the standard `stdbool.h` to define `true` and `false` rather than defining your own enum.

Comment: Make sure `storage.h` is idempotent (can be included twice without causing problems) and self-contained and minimal.  It looks like your header is not idempotent since the previous declaration is in the same file.  And use the standard boolean type — do not roll your own.  Idempotence is achieved by header guards: `#ifndef STORAGE_H_INCLUDED` — `#define STORAGE_H_INCLUDED` at the top of the header and `#endif /* STORAGE_H_INCLUDED` at the bottom.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you can also use '#pragma once' at the top of the header you can check compatibility here: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once#Portability)

Comment: You can if you want to rely on a non-standardized feature, @gabriel; I don't see a need to do so when the standardized mechanism works just fine.  If it becomes part of standard C, I may eventually change my mind; until then, I prefer the tried and trusted mechanism with `#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif`.